# How to count the distance between two words according to the number of sentence in Python?

Tags: python, string, text

I have a dataset, where the `i` and `j` are extracted in two lists. Now I have to check if `i` and `j` in the same sentence it should return `0`, else count the number of sentence between `i` and `j`.

```
a
b
c
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="ne" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="atr">
aa
bb
</coref>
,
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="np" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="atr">
aa
dd
ff
</coref>
 m
 n
 .
# first senetence end here
```

Now I have extracted only the text inside tag `i` to `i_NP` list and `j` to `j_NP` list. How to include the `.` to check if `i` and `j` in the same sentence, then return `0`, else `1`

```
i_NP = []
j_NP = []
find_coref = re.findall(r'<coref.*?coref_coref_class="set.*?>(.*?)</coref>', read_dataset, re.S)
coref_list = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ' '), find_coref))
for i in range(0,len(coref_list)-1,2):
    i_NP.append(str(coref_list[i]))
    j_NP.append(str(coref_list[i+1]))
```

Comment: can you define what you mean by i and j in same sentence? what sentence? you say in a list, are these individual characters? words?

Comment: If you see the sample of the dataset, so I stored the value which is inside the tag `<coref>....</coref>` to `i` and `j`. Now this `i` and `j` are in the same sentence. First, my question is how to define that `i` and `j` are in the same sentence, if `True` return `0` if not in the same sentence then return the number of sentence between `i` and `j`.

Comment: But I annotated each sentence based on `Coreference Resolution` task, therefore, now I want to extract features for this task, and one of the features is the distance between `i` and `j` by the number of the sentence. and if you can see the sample dataset, each sentence ends by `.`